# Dynamics CRM Online - display custom aspx page

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

I need to know that is it possible to display a custom aspx page in online dynamics crm form?

Answer (score 0):

You can display an external page inside an IFRAME on a form **but you cannot host this .aspx page inside CRM**.

If you need to implement special business logic that needs to access external resources, you could create a html webresource that uses js to communicate with a custom workflow action.

Comment: I have tried to include my custom aspx page inside an html web resource but it is still not working.nor it is being displayed in an iframe in crm online

Comment: If you cannot display your .aspx page, very likely your problem isn't embedding it into CRM but hosting it. Are you sure you can access your .aspx page outside the context of CRM? It's really hard to tell without knowing where your .aspx page is hosted.

Comment: @RipalSoni you cannot host the custom aspx page as an `html web resource`